# Trying to run sed command

Tags: command-line, sed

I am trying to run the following sed command that I obviously copy pasted from the internet:

```
sed -i '' -E "s/create_table\ [:\"']([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\"']?/create_table\ :\1, options: 'ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'/g" ./*.rb
```

However it gives me:

```
sed: can't read s/create_table\ [:"']([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)["']?/create_table\ :\1, options: 'ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'/g: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure it out.. could I get some help?

Comment: -i edit files in place :D :)) and add the suffix '' so no suffix

Comment: IIRC in GNU sed, you're not *required* to use an explicit empty backup suffix `''` if you want to overwrite without backup, but if you do it must **immediately** follow the `-i` flag i.e. `-i''`. Otherwise, `''` is treated as an expression - bumping your actual expression into the role of an input file.

Comment: yes, it is correct, post it as the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GNU `sed`, it is not required to provide an empty suffix when using the `-i` option to edit a file in-place without backup. However, if you do, it **must** immediately follow the `-i` with no intervening white space: otherwise, the `''` is interpreted as a sed *expression*, which in turn causes your actual expression `s/pattern/replacement` to be interpreted as a filename.

In summary, the options are:

```
sed -i <other options> <expression> <files>
```

or

```
sed -i'' <other options> <expression> <files>
```